# How to add a nested shortcode into editor?

Tags: shortcode, wp-editor

I want to create an accordion shortcode for wordpress and the html code should be like this:

```
<ul class="acordian">
 <li>
  <h2>sadegh</h2>
  <p>To delete a comment, just log in and view the post’s comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.</p>
 </li>
 <li>
   <h2>sadegh</h2>
   <p>To delete a comment, just log in and view the post’s comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.</p>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h2>sadegh</h2>
  <p>To delete a comment, just log in and view the post’s comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.</p>
 </li>
 <li>
   <h2>sadegh</h2>
   <p>To delete a comment, just log in and view the post’s comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.</p>
</li>
<li>
  <h2>sadegh</h2>
  <p>To delete a comment, just log in and view the post’s comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

For this I've created a nested shortcode with:

```
function Acot($params, $content= null){
    return '<h2>'.$content.'</h2>';
}
add_shortcode('acot','Acot');
function Acotext($params, $content= null){
    return'<p>'.$content.'</p>';
 }
 add_shortcode('acotext','Acotext');
 function Aco($params, $content=null){
return'<ul class="acordian">'.do_shortcode($content).'</ul>';
 }
 add_shortcode('aco','Aco');
 function Acol($params, $content= null){
return'<li>'.do_shortcode($content).'</li>';
  }
 add_shortcode('acol','Acol');
```

I want to add the nested shortcode to editor with one button. Is it possible to do that, and if so, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it developing a TinyMCE plugin and load it using mce_external_plugins hook. The key is in the javascript file of the TinyMCE plugin which will be responsible to pass the nested shortcodes into the editor textarea. You can take a look to [this article](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/01/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/) (about the middle they shows an example of how to add a shortcode button in the editor) or [this one](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/guide-to-creating-your-own-wordpress-editor-buttons/).